# Rscript and simple graph

Tags: r, graph, rstudio, rscript, binary-reproducibility

```
[edit 3] At this point, it is possible for me to use the commands:

library(Cairo)
CairoPNG("test.png")
pie( 1:10, labels=paste("label number",1:10))
dev.off()

to obtain the same figure quality.
```

> Someone with apparently the same problem: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Two-questions-on-R-and-cairo-Cairo-td2318527.html

---

I am wondering why do I obtain different results from the same command using Rstudio, Rscript or just the R console from a terminal. The code I am using is quite clear:

```
png(filename = "test.png")
pie( 1:10, labels=paste("label number",1:10))
dev.off()
```

Image obtained using Rstudio:
[image: Image obtained using Rstudio]

Image obtained using Rscript or the R command prompt from a terminal. (cmd: Rscript script.R )
[image: Image obtained using Rscript/R prompt]

[edit 1] When checking the files I produce, I actually have different size and properties:

```
4,5K test.Rscript.png: PNG image data, 480 x 480, 8-bit colormap, non-interlaced
26K test.Rstudio.png: PNG image data, 480 x 480, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
```

[**edit 2 : Here I need some more help**] Answer from the comment from sinQueso:
The result of

```
Rscript -e 'getOption("bitmapType"); capabilities("cairo");'
"Xlib"
cairo 
FALSE
```

From Rstudio, I got:

```
getOption("bitmapType"); capabilities("cairo");
"cairo"
cairo 
TRUE
```

I checked, I just can not load cairo using the following commands:

```
Error in library(Cairo) : there is no package called ‘Cairo’
Error in library(cairoDevice) : there is no package called ‘cairoDevice’
```

(libcairo2-dev is installed)

So I tried:

```
install.packages('Cairo')
```

from R console, but even if I load the Cairo, I am apparently still using the Xlib.

sessionInfo: The only difference: tools_3.3.2 is loaded in RStudio

Comment: how *exactly* are you saving the graph?  Are you really running those precise three lines of code on each platform (i.e., not doing something like clicking the "save graphic" button in RStudio)?

Comment: I am doing it just by executing the commands one after the other, yes.

Comment: Maybe compare the outputs of `options()`. Just an idea

Comment: I also use Mint 18 and I cannot reproduce: R from the terminal gives me the same proportional font as RStudio

Comment: What is the output of `Rscript -e 'getOption("bitmapType"); capabilities("cairo");'`

Comment: @sinQueso I got that: [1] "Xlib" cairo FALSE Thanks I think this is the good direction. Why is cairo fine in Rstudio but not in Rscript?

Comment: Because it is an add-on package you need to load in your session; RStudio already loads it. There are several package offering it: cairo, cairoDevice, ...  Pick one.

Comment: you could try to force to use cairo by calling `png(..., type="cairo")` (presumably after loading the Cairo package). You'd also want to check that `capabilities("cairo")` returns `TRUE` after loading the package.

Comment: @sinQueso : using `png(..., type="cairo")` does not work. After loading `library(Cairo)` I still have `capabilities("cairo") : FALSE `. But your answer gave me an idea: Using `CairoPNG("test.png")` is working, I actually obtain an image with comparable quality (even a bit bigger in size) when compared to the call in Rstudio.